# Why is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I could use some help with this.

I know that  $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]=\{a+b\sqrt{-5\} }|a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. I then put $$0=(a+b\sqrt{-5})(c+d\sqrt{-5})=ac-5bd+(ad+bc)\sqrt{-5}$$ which leaves me with $$0=ac-5bd$$ and $$0=(ad+bc)\sqrt{-5}$$

now how do I proceed from here? I know that I have to prove $a+b\sqrt{-5}=0$ for $c+d\sqrt{-5}\neq0$.

Comment: Please, do not radically change the subject of the question through editing after it has received an answer (you originally where asking why this ring was a domain but not an UFD). $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is a domain because it is a subring of (say) $\Bbb C$, which is a field.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I didn't 'radically change' anything. I cut the part of the question that was a duplicate, which I didn't know before. What remains as a question is still unanswered. How do I know that it is an integral domain? How does this follow from $\mathbb{C}$ being a field.

Comment: The, it is a subring of $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{-5}]$, which is a field.

Comment: Sorry, why are subrings of fields integral domains?

Comment: Because subrings of integral domains are integral domains, and fields are integral domains.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thank you. And is there a way to calculate directly from $a*b=0$ with $a,b$ being complex numbers and $b\neq 0$ that $a=0$?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part : numbers in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ are in particular complex numbers. What happens when a product of two complex numbers is zero ?

For the second part : to show that your elements irreducible, try to see that no element has its norm equal to $2$ or $3$ (the norm of $a+b\sqrt{-5}$ is $a^2+5b^2$).

Comment: Regarding the first part: Both real and imaginary part of the product are zero?

Comment: Well, yes, but that's a weird way to put it (you don't have to make any reference to real or imaginary parts). If $xy=0$ then $x=0$ and $y=0$ : $\mathbb{C}$ is integral. In general, you can see your first question as a special case of : a subring of an integral ring is integral.

Comment: Ok but I want to prove this, not assume it.

Comment: But don't you already know that if $x,y\in \mathbb{C}$ then $xy=0$ implies $x=0$ and $y=0$ ?

Comment: No. Can I prove it without using that $\mathbb{C}$ is a field?

Comment: Well, I guess you can, but is there such a thing as a course where you learn the notion of UFD but can't use the fact that complex numbers have a division ?

Comment: How do I do it?